# XamlParseException for accessing XML File when publishing WPF XBAP Project

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml, xbap

I have a XML file in my XBAP project which is accessed by classes in it.I am able to get the path of file using

`System.IO.Path.Combime(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"Filename.xml")`

and access it using

```
XDocument.Load(Obatinedpath)
```

For some reason when I publish my project it adds a path to AppData Folder and throws an

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
```

does not work, it gives a path in the AppData folder of system. I have also changed the properties of file to BiuldAction: Content and Copy to Output Directory: Copy Always and tried to make a direct access, this too does not work. Can someone please help me find a way to access the file when it is published?

Comment: `XamlParseException` is usually a wrapper around another exception.  Check the `InnerException` property on it. You usually get a more helpful message there.

Comment: How is this a XAML problem?

Comment: Can you show the header of the XAML?

Comment: The inner exception is System.IO.FileNotFoundException